# Segmentation fault when trying to run multiple programs

Tags: debian, segmentation-fault

So the other day I wanted to install an alternative video editor on my computer (since Camtasia doesn't support Linux). I tried installing DaVinci Resolve. When I ran the installer it asked me to install the following packages:

```
libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-damage0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0
```

I installed them and went on with the installation. After the installation I tried to run DaVinci Resolve but it kept crashing for some reason. I did some search and concluded that my old GPU doesn't support it.

I uninstalled DaVinci and decided to try out Kdenlive. I installed it and tried to run it but again it kept crashing. Specifically it opened the Kdenlive window but immediately closed on it's own.

I tried to find the problem by running Kdenlive from the terminal and it spit out a Segmentation fault message. I thought it was a problem with the program itself but then I tried to run Unity it crashed too.

Ran Unity from the terminal and it also gave me the Segmentation fault error. I then attempted to delete those packages that I installed for DaVinci but that didn't solve my problem. Please help. I'm running Debian 11 stable.

**Edit:** I used GDB debugging tool to try and find more details about what the problem is and when I got the segmentation fault error it printed out:

```
0x00007fffeef6f03d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

So the problem seems to be with this specific file. How do I fix it?

@berndbausch I ran the `dmesg` command and it gave me a couple errors about the firmware but I don't think it's a ram problem since Unity was launching before. Anyway here are the errors it gave me:

```
[0.083570] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[0.083162] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff]
               BIOS vendor: Insyde; Ver: F.36; Product Version: 0975120000405F00000610180
[1.253291] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECRD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200925/psargs-330)
[1.253345] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200925/psparse-529)
[1.253486] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECRD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200925/psargs-330)
[1.253535] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200925/psparse-529)
[1.253627] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECRD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200925/psargs-330)
[1.253675] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200925/psparse-529)
[1.253759] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECRD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200925/psargs-330)
[1.253810] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200925/psparse-529)
[16.093613] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin (-2)
[16.093654] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[16.093693] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
```

Comment: Might be insufficient RAM? Do you see anything in the kernel message buffer (`dmesg` command)?

Comment: 1. Bad RAM? memtest86/memtest86+ could check it. 2. Corrupted files on the disk? 3. Not enough RAM?

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions in comments, especially when you're adding some error messages or other lines like this. Instead [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738593/edit) your original question to add new info. No need this time - I did it for you, the edit will be visible once another member of the community approves it. Once it's there, you can delete that comment.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No inconvenience at all, friend, it's part of being in these communities :-) These sites are good like that, on top of the excellent advice one gets. For a newbie it's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help). Also just checking out the questions others have posted is helpful in learning how these communities work.

Comment: @berndbausch I added the dmesg error outputs to the question.

Comment: There is nothing about this process in the message buffer. Since you are not afraid running gdb, I also recommend `strace` or `ltrace` to see at which system or library call it crashes.